# how to draw a dashed path in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to draw a brick curved path but i need to be able to put an arrow pointing to any a brick by API. something like this:

[image: The road]

i thought to use canvas but i'm not sure i can get a reference to each brick and fire events.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 canvas has no memory of specific shapes which were drawn to it. So you are responsible for remembering where you drew each brick polygon. You could simply create an array where you store the coordinate-pairs for each brick. In fact many games which use HTML5 canvas work that way: The positions and visual information of all objects in the game are stored in data structures which are separated from the canvas. The canvas gets completely erased each frame and then gets redrawn from scratch.

Another option is to use an [SVG object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) instead of a canvas. SVG is also a form of mutable image element, but it is shape-oriented, not pixel-oriented. That means it is possible to assign IDs to objects you add to an SVG document tree and later find and manipulate them by ID. You can even attach mouse event handlers to individual objects in an SVG image.

Comment: I'd go with SVG and then render it to the canvas element. I believe there is a native Javascript API that allows for that.

Comment: @DimuDesigns Yes, you can use an SVG as a source for `canvasContext.drawImage`. I have done that before. It can be useful if you want to combine vector graphics with pixel-level effects. But it has the disadvantage that you miss out on some of the advantages of SVG that way, like the ability to use event handlers on individual SVG elements and flawless zooming.